# Custom chapter number with titlesec and geometry: number past page border

Tags: xetex, titlesec, geometry

I have used the titlesec package and geometry package to get the following chapter style (note that I'm using XeLaTeX):

[image: Chapter style as I have it now]

This works, however I am unable to align the chapter number in the way I would like to have it. Additionally, chapters with two numbers go over the page border:

[image: Long chapter numbers go over the page border]

This is how I would like to format it:

[image: Chapter numbers should be right aligned with the title rule.]

Chapter numbers should be right aligned with the title rule.
This is a MWE of how it is now:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,11pt,fleqn,openright]{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}

% Fonts
\usepackage{mathspec}

\makeatletter % undo the wrong changes made by mathspec
\let\RequirePackage\original@RequirePackage
\let\usepackage\RequirePackage
\makeatother

\ifdefined\suppressfontnotfounderror
  \expandafter\let\csname xetex_suppressfontnotfounderror:D\endcsname
    \suppressfontnotfounderror
\else
  \expandafter\let\csname xetex_suppressfontnotfounderror:D\endcsname
    \luatexsuppressfontnotfounderror
\fi

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O}
\setmonofont[Mapping=tex-ansi,Path=../fonts/,UprightFont=InconsolataRegular.ttf,BoldFont=InconsolataBold.ttf]{InconsolataRegular.ttf}
\setmathfont[math-style=ISO, bold-style=ISO]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

% use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}

% use microtype if available
\usepackage[final=true]{microtype}
\microtypecontext{spacing=french}
\UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath}

\usepackage[a4paper,includeheadfoot,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{mydarkestpurple}{rgb}{0.18,0.035,0.38}

\def\myrulewidth{0.4mm}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
{\relax}{\mbox{}\marginpar{\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\color{mydarkestpurple}\fontsize{78}{94}\selectfont\thechapter}}{0pt}%
    {\Huge\bfseries\color{mydarkestpurple} #1}[\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titleline{\color{mydarkestpurple}\titlerule}]% 
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0cm}{1cm}

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}
\lipsum[1]
\setcounter{chapter}{9}
\chapter{Ten}
\lipsum[2]


\end{document}
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code that does what you want. You really don't want the chapter numbers in the margin, but at the left of the right margin, so I used the `\filleft` command from titlesec.

I had to remove the path to `Inconsolata` (which I do not have; I replaced it with the version that comes with MiKTeX, and is in the path).

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,11pt,fleqn,openright]{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}

% Fonts
\usepackage{mathspec}

\makeatletter % undo the wrong changes made by mathspec
\let\RequirePackage\original@RequirePackage
\let\usepackage\RequirePackage
\makeatother

\ifdefined\suppressfontnotfounderror
  \expandafter\let\csname xetex_suppressfontnotfounderror:D\endcsname
    \suppressfontnotfounderror
\else
  \expandafter\let\csname xetex_suppressfontnotfounderror:D\endcsname
    \luatexsuppressfontnotfounderror
\fi

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O}
\setmonofont[Mapping=tex-ansi,UprightFont=Inconsolatazi4-Regular.otf,BoldFont=Inconsolatazi4-Bold.otf]{InconsolataRegular.ttf}

\setmathfont[math-style=ISO, bold-style=ISO]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

% use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}

% use microtype if available
\usepackage[final=true]{microtype}
\microtypecontext{spacing=french}
\UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath}

\usepackage[a4paper,includeheadfoot,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{mydarkestpurple}{rgb}{0.18,0.035,0.38}

\def\myrulewidth{0.6mm}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]%
{\color{mydarkestpurple}}{}{0pt}%
    {\parbox[b]{0.75\textwidth}{\Huge\bfseries#1}\hfill \fontsize{78}{94}\selectfont\thechapter}[\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}{\titlerule[\myrulewidth]}]%
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0cm}{1cm}

\begin{document}

\chapter{One }
\lipsum[1]
\setcounter{chapter}{9}
\chapter{Ten.\\ Tweedledum And Tweedledee}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is already very nice. How can I get the chapter title and number at the same baseline height?

Comment: I thought you wanted them on different levels, since you used the `display` style. May your titles be longer than one line?

Comment: I used the `display` style only because the example code I found used it. I have not decided on chapter names yet, so they could possibly be longer than one line.

Comment: It's the `block` style that is useful in this context. Please see my updated answer. I've put the title in a `\parbox` so that it can't overlap the chapter number, and I managed to have a title rule of the width you want. Let me know if it's OK now.

Comment: Very nice! I knew about the `block` comment but wasn't able to get this result because I didn't know about `\parbox`. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. It's a pleasure.